# Should I reload data from REST service or add localy when posting new data in single page application

Tags: angularjs, rest, single-page-application

For example we have simple single page application for TODO list. When user adds new item to the list how would you recommend to populate the list of todos.

1. POST new item to REST service and on success reload data from REST service or
2. POST new item to REST service and add item to list localy

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to you, and depends on if you need to get anything back from the server, like an `id` property, it also depends on whether or not your list is filtered in any way server side.  If it is, the item may or may not be included.  Specifically for a TODO list I might just add it to the list instead of reloading the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to make the application as responsive as possible. So what I'd do is ensure that the changes reflect on the browser as soon as possible, and then work on the promise from the `$http` to rollback the changes in case there's a failure.

[documentation for $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

You can do something as simple as

```
$http({url: '/something'})
    .success(function() { /*do something*/ })
    .error(function() { /*uh-oh*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Option (1) is more robust as it will identify any problems made during the save. It should also provide you with the resource ID which you will need if you then want to later edit and save that todo item; without it you would not know which item to update (unless you are saving everything in a NoSQL type way)